# Would Gollum qualify, as a Ringbearer, to go to the Undying Lands?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

If Gollum had not died in Mount Doom, would he have been *allowed* to join the elves, Bilbo, and Frodo in the Undying Lands?

He was, after all, by far the longest-lasting bearer of the One Ring (not counting Sauron himself before it was taken from him), which is the reason given for Frodo, Bilbo, and Sam’s being allowed to go there.

And would his being or not being allowed to go to the Undying Lands be affected by whether or not the Gollum part of him would vanish after the destruction of the Ring, leaving only Sméagol behind?

***Note:*** As Richard’s answer (with comments) points out, there are various logistical practicalities that would likely get in the way of Gollum ever getting anywhere. However, what I am asking here is **whether whoever decides who is and isn’t allowed to go to the Undying Lands would consider Gollum, as a Ringbearer, *qualified* to go there.**

Comment: Something which none of the answers have currently touched upon is that I might argue that Gollum wasn't a "ringbearer". The purpose of the ringbearer was to carry it to its destruction, not just to be in possession of it.

Comment: @MattTaylor I don't recall Bilbo going any length to destroy it…

Comment: @Lohoris - sure he did. He got it from the possession of a bad character to possession of Frodo and attention of Gandalf

Comment: "He was, after all, by far the longest-lasting ringbearer […]" Not by a long shot. By the time of LOTR, Galadriel had had [Nenya](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Nenya) for millennia. Ditto for at least some of the [bearers of the three rings](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Ring-bearer). And [Sauron carried the One Ring for almost 2000 years](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/One_Ring#List_of_Ring-bearers). Although he probably burned that whole "Go West" bridge some time ago.

Comment: @l0b0 I was referring only to bearers of the One Ring here (though of course bearers of the other rings are ringbearers, too), and excluding Sauron himself as the Ring’s maker. I’ll edit to clarify.

Comment: @DVK Smeagol retrieved from a river, when it was believed lost, and untimately, when the time was ripe, handed it down to a worthy character.

Comment: I don't think the Elves got to choose who got to go to the Undying Lands. I also don't know about Illuvatar's part in this either. What about the Valar? They brought the Elves from Middle Earth in the First Age and were dead-set against them leaving to try to retrieve the Silmarils. Don't they get to choose who gets to come back?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. If you have a new question please ask it by clicking the "Ask Question" button in the upper right corner. This space is reserved for answers.

Comment: @Lohoris Not willingly...

Comment: @reirab Nor did Bilbo, really. It took quite a bit of, shall we say, _encouragement_ from Gandalf to get him to give it up.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Bilbo did willingly give it up, though. It had to be stolen from Sméagol (and, even after that, he tried desperately to get it back.) I'd say even that Bilbo gave it up more freely than Frodo did.

Comment: Remember how the elf-rope burned Golum's skin in RotK(the book, at least)? Think what stepping into the Undying Lands would do -- allowing him to go there would NOT be a reward.

Comment: @LindaJeanne - We don't know if the rope actually burned his skin - all we know is that he *said* it burned his skin.  He may have been lying because he didn't like being tied up, he may have imagined that it was burning his skin, or it may have actually burned his skin.  We can rarely take what people say in Tolkien at face value - they sometimes lie, but most of the time they say what they believe - but we almost never know whether or not they are right.

Comment: @o0' Bilbo was the only being who freely chose to give up the ring

Comment: @a_a Technically Sam gave it up freely too.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I would dispute the premise of the question. It is said that Legolas took Gimli too to the Undying Lands, and Gimli was never a ringbearer. Bilbo and Frodo (and later Sam) went because they were invited, for the healing of their pain. And they were invited because they had done great deeds and, basically, had earned it. If Gimli went, as it is rumoured, he did so for similar reasons, and also for the sake of his great friendship with Legolas.

The qualifying criterion, then, was not as simple as “being a ringbearer”, and there is no way that Sméagol would have been invited to sail the straight path.

Comment: Very good point! I had not thought about Gimli here at all.

Comment: I've heard it said that those with the title of "Elf-friend" were permitted to go, which was why Gimli was allowed to go. I don't remember if that's canon or not, and I don't have a copy of the Appendices handy to verify.

Comment: I was going to comment on the other answer about Gimli being allowed, and not being a Ring Bearer, but you've got it here so +1.

Comment: I think this answer’s pointing out the false premise underlying my question is ultimately the best possible answer there is, so I am going to accept this answer.

Answer (score 62):

I'm not aware of any canonical reasons why he would or wouldn't, so I'll draw on what we know about the Elves, Rings, and the Undying Lands. I seriously doubt they'd let Gollum join them for three main reasons.

**The Hobbits were an exception**
Until the end of ROTK, the Undying Lands were basically exclusively for Elves. But, as Gandalf hinted at, Bilbo was "meant" to have the Ring, which in turn meant that Frodo was "meant" to have it (and by extension, Sam, who bears it for quite a while in the book). But who intended for this to happen? Gandalf's hint seems to lead us to believe that some other force or power conspired to make it so. While not explicitly stated, it's within reason to say that Eru himself intervened and led Bilbo to find it. This is speculation, but I think it's within reason, seeing as how Gandalf has a knowledge of a great many things (and wasn't just trying to give a pep talk to Frodo). So, since the Hobbits were chosen by the Creator himself, they were granted admittance to the Undying Lands. Gollum wouldn't have been afforded that same benefit.

**Gollum was already "stretched too thin"**
After losing the Ring, Bilbo himself barely made it. Gollum was much, much older, and in much worse shape. Even if he made it to the Havens, and even if he made the journey, mortals still die in the Undying Lands (oddly enough). It just wouldn't be practical to fix up an express boat just to get him there before he kicked the bucket.

**Gollum was inherently evil**
I think this is the most important point. Notice how when Smeagol first laid eyes on the Ring, he instantly wanted it. Within moments, he succumbed to the Ring's influence and murdered Deagol. This isn't the work of an inherently "good" person. Frodo, Sam, and Bilbo all treated the Ring as a "precious" thing, but none of them killed over it. Frodo came close, but that was when the Ring was doing its utmost to dominate his will. For this reason above all others, I think the Elves would deny him asylum. You could even extend this logic to explain why the Nine, the Seven, or even Sauron himself would not be allowed to make the trip.

Again, this is just the best explanation I could come up with based on the established lore.

Comment: I don't think it is fair to say that Gollum was inherently evil. It seems that Tolkien never thought of him that way. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/was-gollum-evil

Answer (score 10):

Had Gollum not died at the Crack of Doom, it's reasonably likely that he would have died shortly afterwards. Note that Bilbo's age caught up with him after the One Ring's destruction;

> ...Bilbo was sitting in a chair before a small bright fire. He looked
>   very old, but peaceful, and sleepy. He opened his eyes and looked up
>   as they came in. 'Hullo, hullo!' he said. 'So you've come back? And
>   tomorrow's my birthday, too. How clever of you! Do you know, I shall
>   be one hundred and twenty-nine? And in one year more, if I am spared,
>   I shall equal the Old Took. I should like to beat him; but we shall
>   see.'

Since Smeagol was hundreds of years old, had he not committed suicide **or** dived into the fire in the hopes of rescuing the One Ring **or** been instantly destroyed by its destruction (as was Sauron), he would simply have just died of old age.

That being the case, a trip to the Undying Lands would have been out of the question.

Comment: I don’t know how _immediate_ it was, exactly … as far as I can recall, there’s no mention (at least not in _LotR_) of Bilbo’s ageing process during the seventeen or so years between his disappearance from the Shire and Frodo’s seeing him in Rivendell. It could just as well have happened gradually, could it not?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I was under the impression that it was immediate. Let me have a quick read.

Comment: Bilbo's aging was rapid, but not terribly quick. If Gollum hadn't died, he surely would have lasted at least a few more years, certainly long enough to make it to the Havens. But what would have happened then?

Comment: At any rate, Gollum had already gone without the Ring for about 60-odd years by the time of _LotR_ without dying or growing significantly older. The actual destruction of the Ring doesn’t seem to have as much of an effect on Ringbearers, age-wise, as the act of ceasing to be a Ringbearer, if Bilbo’s ageing is anything to go by: he aged before the Ring was destroyed.

Comment: Or perhaps I am misremembering, getting the movie mixed up with the books. In the movie, if I’m not mistaken, Bilbo is already significantly aged when Frodo first reaches Rivendell. But I’ve just scanned that bit in the book, and apart from Bilbo saying “I am getting old” (which is natural: his ageing would at the very least resume at a natural pace without the Ring on him), there is no mention of him being older. So perhaps he _doesn’t_ age before the Ring is destroyed after all. Even so, as @Rhettorical says, there should be enough time for Gollum to get to the Havens if he’d survived.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Mortals [still die](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39920/did-the-ring-bearers-and-gimli-die-in-valinor/51711#51711) in the undying lands

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The movies don't dwell too long on what happens after the Ring is destroyed, or at least not on how much time passes (we know Frodo wrote down his adventures and Sam had two kids but those are the only clues). The book specifies how much time passes, but I don't remember how long off the top of my head. Bilbo looked near-death in the film, so I can't imagine Gollum lasting all those years. He'd have to get to the Havens in a couple years, tops, I think, and be the first one to leave. Probably. He'd still die there, anyway, so it might not even matter.

Comment: @Rhettorical True, he would have to find a ship to take him there before he croaked it—but the question here is more one of _permission_ than practical matters. Assuming that he survives at least long enough to get to the Havens (plus however long the actual journey is) and there just happens to be a delegation on their way to the Undying Lands, _who gets to decide whether he qualifies to go? And what would their decision be?_

Comment: @Rhettorical i mean bilbo appeared to have aged 20+ years after about a year, while gollum was 500+ years old, i feel like he would have died in days-months max. ring destroyed in 3019, leave to grey havens in 3021. so in 2 years the 60+ had completely caught up, and he was hanging on by a thread it appears in the books, id say richard is right and gollum woulda been dead real quick.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I suppose that is what we're trying to figure out... My best reasoning (knowing what I know about Elves and whatnot) is that they wouldn't let him any more than they'd let any of the Nine or the Seven. I think the primary reasons would be (a) the Hobbits were a large exception, and they were (as Gandalf said/hinted at) chosen by Eru himself, (b) Gollum was already "stretched too thin", so he probably wouldn't have survived long or at all, and (c) Gollum was inherently evil from the start, seeing as how he killed to get the Ring immediately after first laying eyes on it.

Comment: @Rhettorical Good point about the Nine and the Seven—hadn’t thought about them. That comment is an upvote-worthy answer!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet :) I did my best. Might I suggest clarifying the title of the question to reflect whether or not he'd be granted permission?

Comment: @Rhettorical Done. :-)

Comment: I'm tempted to delete this answer given the edit. ..

Comment: @Richard Don't—it's still a good, useful answer, even if it's a bit orthogonal to the intention of the question.

Comment: I thought that in the book, when Frodo met Bilbo at Rivendell, there was some mention that Bilbo still seemed to be unusually youthful for his age.  I will try to find it later.

Comment: No, I seem to be mistaken.  I didn't find any description of Bilbo's physical appearance at that point in the book.

Answer (score 5):

LOTR is all about redemption, as has been said oft-times in answers to other questions on this SE. Gollum had the opportunity to act righteously, to assist the Fellowship to destroy the Ring (or at least not interfere), but instead, he chose to act in his own interest. Smeagol's struggle versus Gollum in the Marshes is a part of that drama. The reader gains hope that Smeagol may win out, and his soul be redeemed. The two are not separate beings, but one and the same, and so must ultimately be accountable for his choices.

I think Gollum/Smeagol is perhaps the greatest tragedy in LOTR. He succumbs and acts in self-interest, so he can never attain that which would have brought him peace. If he had made the better choice, to defeat absolute evil, I would say he would definitely be eligible for the Grey Havens -- maybe in a more agreeable physical form. He might die beforehand, but not because he's old. He was already ancient, many times the normal lifespan of a hobbit, so old age alone wouldn't be enough to kill him. He had already been without the Ring for decades, so another few years would be ok. What might do him in is that perhaps his soul was  too tightly connected to the Ring. Once it was destroyed, he might not be able to maintain his corporeal self any longer.

Comment: The ability to control one's own destiny is actually a pretty common theme across a lot of beliefs. It's by no means a "very Christian" concept. Also, I think Tolkien wouldn't appreciate trying to attribute his work to any religion, even his own. I don't think that information is pertinent to your answer, anyway.

Comment: Tolkien attributed his work to his religion.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Gollum and Smeagol were two separate persons.  The "character" the ring was capable of evoking in such creatures as Galadriel (instead of a dark lord you would have a dark queen) and Gandalf (through me it would wield too great a power) indicate that even they (Elflord and Maia wielder of Narya) would exhibit profound darkness if the ring were given the chance to do so.

If Gandalf and Galadriel are as susceptible to become dark rulers, then it is likely the person of Gollum is a manifestation of the ring itself through the being and person of Smeagol.  I think that the degree of cunning and malice exhibited in Gollum shows the character of Sauron.

The construction shows that "into the ring was poured malice" and "will to dominate".  Those are attributes of intentionality, and were done with purpose in aiding the ring of rings to achieve for Sauron what he intended.

The one ring is meant to be a ruling ring of rings.  The rings were meant to cause leaders of a race to be able to evoke the most characteristic excellences of the races.  The "center of elvendom on earth", Lothloriedorinian, came into being as it was in part by the use of the Elven rings.  The great dwarven kingdoms likely have similar correlation.  The ring was meant to make rings of rulership more rings of rulership - more capable.

The rings that were not hidden were poisoned by the one ring.  The darkness poured into the one ring, leaked out through the others and into their bearers.  Greed to the dwarves.   I think that humans succumb more quickly to both the greatness and the darkness of the rings.  Yeah - a fair bit of supposition.  Gandalfs attribution of resistance to the ring by the Hobbits was due their race, not their character.  They seem to be children of a different Valar - and as such not under the ring.  I think Tolkien may have envisioned them as the "wee folk" of the Irish.

In the end, when Frodo fell to the ring, and claimed it for his own, it was the action of Smeagol that resulted in the destruction of the ring.  It is a proof that evil, especially the character of Sauron could not live in a world with a copy of itself.  It is a demonstration of the self-annihilation of evil.  I think that, in a Tolkien world, while there is redemption, it is never cheap.  Often, like the case of Grimma, it is accomplished at the cost of ones life.  The destructiveness of even a little darkness is very great and it takes a lot of good blood spilled to quench it.

While I agree that the unnatural long life granted by the one ring evaporated as the ring did, I think in principle that Smeagol would have been welcome on distant shores.  In an ironic way the thing that cost Smeagol his life, would have counted as sufficient for redemption.

EDIT: If being ringbearer alone was a qualification to go to undying lands would it not thus qualify both Isildur and Sauron to go there? I think there must be some additional or alternative criteria there.

Comment: To the reviewer who rejected my changes - what is the proper way to include exact quotes as references, and what they are?  I was surprised at the rejection of the edit, and equally surprised that there exists no linked feedback mechanism to ask questions or improve my interactions.  Pass/Fail is much less informative than some limited direction in how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Let's not forget the forgiving nature of the Valar. It's stated that they could not comprehend evil, and therefore had no way to punish it. It's only when Tulkas is sent to Arda, that justice is served to Morgoth, and even then he is redeemed of his actions for a short while through his deceptions. Sauron, despite his actions through the servitude of Morgoth is _still_ invited for redemption. It wouldn't be completely out of the question to assume that this invitation would be extended to a lesser, more naturally innocent being, as his actions do indirectly cause the destruction of the ring.

Comment: Gandalf learned compassion in the company of the valar.

Comment: It's stated in books that he learned this from the house of Nienna.

Answer (score -3):

In Tolkien's retelling of the Judeo-Christian creation, the fall of man, and the reconciliation of the angels, the Havens represent Heaven and the Elves the fallen angels.  The fallen angels are allowed to return to Heaven because they have reconciled themselves with God.

Given a concept of divine forgiveness, Gollum would be accepted into Heaven if he repented his evil ways.

Comment: Lord of the Rings is not an allegory, though. Tolkien flatly denied any such association and labelled any such associations as pure speculation.

Comment: I politely disagree.  Tolkien rejected the interpretation of his ring story in terms of history (one assumes he had in mind the rise and fall of Nazi Germany).  He did not refer to The Silmarillion.  In any event I am not claiming that The Silmarillion was an allegory.  It was a retelling of a religious story.  That is not allegory.

Comment: Tolkien was a devout Christian. It is clear from the opening pages of The Silmarillion that he is retelling the Creation etc. In his last poem he recounts the grim prospect of his impending death (going West, "the waves are grey"), states his rejection of despair ("islands lie beyond the Sun that I shall raise err all is done"), and in the final line of his and Bilbo's last poem he reaffirms his religious faith ("I see thy star above my mast").

Comment: If any allegory or symbolism is to be found, it's pure speculation, and according to Tolkien, completely not intentional. He was often very critical of allegory, going so far as to criticize his friend C.S. Lewis, who often wrote overtly allegorical stories. As he said: ["I cordially dislike allegory in all its manifestations, and always have done since I grew old and wary enough to detect its presence."](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/27748.html)

Comment: Let us disagree in a friendly way.  If one believes in the Bible, as I do not, then it is allegory.  If the Bible is a story that provides guidance to the faithful, then it is not allegory or symbolism.  Shakespeare's King Lear is based on a story by Raphael Holinshed.  We would call King Lear a retelling not an allegory.  In as much as Tolkien was devout, The Silmarillion would, indeed, be an allegory in his mind.  However, I believe Tolkien was referring the the ring story as not being an allegory, not to The Silmarillion.  The congruence with the Creation etc. is too compelling in mind.

Comment: The creation account of the Silmarillion differs greatly enough from the Biblical account that it's in no way allegorical. It's just another creation mythos. Any similarities are just the result of many creation accounts being naturally similar.

Comment: @Rhettorical I'd say Silmarillion was probably more heavily influenced by the Bible than perhaps even Tolkien cared to admit, but I agree that it's still not an allegory and does contain rather significant differences.

Comment: @reirab All of Tolkien's work was heavily influenced by his personal beliefs, as is the case with many writers. That's why people often find WWI and WWII symbolism in LOTR, or parallels between the Bible and his works. But, the pantheon of deity-like beings in his mythos is one of the biggest places where the analogy breaks down. The Ainur are less like Biblical angels (who aren't depicted as interfering in earthly matters), and more like minor gods themselves, as is shown in the Silmarillion. In that sense, they have more in common with Greek, Roman, or Norse gods.

Comment: Why in the world would you think it is a retelling of Judeo-Christian cosmogony? It has very little in common with it. The themes Tolkien plays with are present in many religions, notably the Norse and even Greek mythologies. The Elves are not fallen angels, they were created by the Ainur (who you might consider orthologs of angels). Even if the Silmarillion were an allegory (which I very much doubt), I see no reason to assume it was a Judeo-Christian one. No messiah, for one thing.

Comment: @terdon: the elves are NOT created by the Ainur... they are the first children of Illuvatar, so created by the supreme god himself. The Ainurs are not really gods, they can't create life. Their power is the shaping of things already existing, being in that sense more akin to elves than to Illuvatar. That said, Tolkien was a faithful christian, and as such, his work can't help being inspired by the Bible. And he says so himself. When asked in an interview who Illavatar is, he replied something along the line: "Well, he is the ONE." So that is starting from the top.

Comment: @Joel true, my bad. I must have been confusing them with the dwarves. My point was that if anyone is a "fallen angel", that would be the Ainur (specifically, the Valar), not the elves. Many religions have a single "boss" deity, that's no reason to equate Tolkien's world with the Judeo-Christian tradition.

Comment: Christianity is certainly inspired by many religions that went before. But Tolkien was clearly putting in his christian beliefs into his creation, even though it is true he also did so with most other european mythologies. I see Manwë more like Zeus or Odin than as a kind of archangel Michael. It's not all black or all white.