# Are Frodo and Bilbo immortal after they go to Valinor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, undying-lands

In the end of the last film Frodo and Bilbo gain Access to Valinor.
Are they immortal like the elves when they get there or do they die "normal"?

Comment: Related question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39920/did-the-ring-bearers-and-gimli-die-in-valinor?rq=1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From Tolkien's letter #325:

> As for Frodo or other mortals [who enter Valinor], they could only dwell in Aman for a limited time - whether brief or long. The Valar had neither the power nor the right to confer "immortality" upon them. Their sojorn was a "purgatory", but one of peace and healing and they would eventually pass away (die at their own desire and of free will) to destinations of which the Elves knew nothing.

Also, from letter #154:

> I have said nothing about it in this book, but the mythical idea underlying is that for mortals, since their 'kind' cannot be changed for ever, this is strictly only a temporary reward: a healing and redress of suffering. They cannot abide for ever, and though they cannot return to mortal earth, they can and will 'die' - of free will, and leave the world.

So no, they can't be made to live forever, but they could live quite a while.

[Source attribution.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/do-frodo-and-bilbo-live-forever-at-the-end-of-the-lord-of-the-rings-trilogy)

Comment: So they only die if they want to but it's guaranteed that they do want to die at some point? Am I reading this right?

Comment: @AndréStannek: They will grow old. Perhaps at a slower rate, but they will. And old age, even if free of suffering, will make you want to pass away at some point.

Comment: @DevSolar I'm not sure that's all. If it was, why isn't Elrond super depressed? And why would he be against Arwen giving up her immortality for Aragorn? Like André I wanna know what exactly guarantees that the person in question will eventually give in and die of free will.

Comment: @Kevin: For one, Elrond IS immortal, and does NOT grow old. (Though even Elves grow weary of Middle-Earth and sail west, though for different reasons.) As for Arwen, chosing Aragorn will take her away from him, not just for now but for eternity. These things are so different from Frodo in Valinor that I do not understand how you came up with them?

Comment: @DevSolar Yes exactly, he is immortal, yet you state "even if free of suffering, will make you want to pass away at some point", obviously Elrond doesn't want to die yet. If Elrond is immortal and doesn't want to die, what makes sure that Humans with a long life eventually DO want to die?

Comment: @Kevin Elrond may not want to 'die', but he is pretty keen on leaving Middle-Earth. Just as Elves get tired of the world of Men, so too would Men get tired of the world of Elves.

Comment: All the half-elves (Elrond and Arwen included) were given the right to choose between an Elven or Human lifespan. Elrond had already made his choice in the First/Second age, and Arwen when she decided to marry Aragorn (the movie has her saying "I choose a mortal's life").

Comment: @Kevin: I said that *old age* will make you want to pass on. Elrond doesn't *age*.

Comment: @Mindwin That's not true, only the line of Luthien is allowed to choose between mortality and immortality. Elrond chose to stay immortal, but his brother (Elros ) chose to become mortal. He became the ruler of Gondor and is Aragorn's ancestor. Other elves don't have this choice.

Comment: @DevSolar Ah I see, that makes it more clear. Thank you :)

Comment: @Kevin: Only *half*-elves get that choice. And I am only aware of that one line of half-elves -- Elros and Elrond.

Comment: @Kevin "Only the line of Luthien"... Elrond -> Arwen? Arwen is descendant of Luthien. Also, as DevSolar said, it is not Elves, but the Half-Elves. Arwen is a half-elf.

Comment: @AndréStannek _Like butter spread ever thinner..._ - Bilbo Baggins

Comment: Randomly came to mind: Frodo saying to Bilbo: "*We can die if we want too - We can leave your friends behind - 'Cause your friends don't die and if they don't die - Well, they're no friends of mine.*"